# Looping in excel VBA

Tags: excel

Could someone teach me how to loop through this. The cell that changes is A12 to A13 all the way till A30

```
Sheets("Macro").Select
With Sheets("ONE")
    'loop column N until last cell with value (not entire column)
     For Each Cell In .Range("N1:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value = Range("A12") Then
             ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("NEW").Rows(Cell.Row)
        End If
     Next Cell
     End With

Sheets("Macro").Select
With Sheets("ONE")
    'loop column N until last cell with value (not entire column)
     For Each Cell In .Range("N1:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value = Range("A13") Then
             ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("NEW").Rows(Cell.Row)
        End If
     Next Cell
     End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Dim i as Long

With Sheets("ONE")
    'loop column N until last cell with value (not entire column)
     For i=1 to .Cells(.Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cell(i, 14).Value = Range("A12").Value Then
             ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
            .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("NEW").Rows(i)
        elseIf Cell(i, 14).Value = Range("A13").Value Then
               ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
            .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("NEW").Rows(i)
        End If
     Next Cell
End With
```

Anyhow, consider that if the value is not equal to A12 or A13 there will be no data copied. Hope it helps

Comment: It's a good answer, but I'll make a couple points to improve it. First, you're calculating the last row every single time the loop comes back to the top; it's more efficient to create a variable `Dim lastRow As Long; lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row` and use that as the upper bound to your loop. Second is that you're mixing references to the `With` clause using `.Cells` and references to the currently active sheet `Cells` (without the leading `.`). Be careful with your references because there are different sheets being referenced.

Comment: I was just trying to keep as much code as possible of the original post, so the answer will be easier to understand. I won't do in that way, but then, there will be too many changes.